# Undefined variable: session_priv

Tags: php, content-management-system

Greetings I still having probs with my php code,
the error message is

> undefined variable : session_priv
>   Really

the code for authenticating login is here http://pastebin.com/crxvzTBr

the content code is http://pastebin.com/xr2PxbNG

Thank You in advance bro :)

Comment: That's because you're defining it as `$_SESSION["session_priv"]` and then using it as `$session_priv`. The two are not the same.

Comment: SO I must create a variable to accept the $_SESSION["session_priv"] ?

Comment: Or you can use `$_SESSION["session_priv"]` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$session_priv =  $_SESSION["session_priv"];`

OR

use `$_SESSION["session_priv"]` wherever you used `$session_priv`